# Multi-Arch Dockerfile - is there a way to select which source to COPY based on Architecture

Tags: docker, multiarch

Yes, `RUN yum install` works for either, but if you want to execute `COPY gosu /usr/bin/gosu` is there a way to selectively copy gosu-arm64 and gosu-armv7 depending on the target architecture?

I looked, did not find anything, now looking for skunkwork solutions...

Comment: Is the gosu cross compile binary which is used for multi arch docker image?

Comment: Nope, gosu is availably downloadable as different architectures, but its not a gosu related question either, I want to solve this problem for any architecture-specific copy statement.